# Context-free grammars for two languages

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

How do I write context-free grammars for the following languages?

1. $B_2 = \{0^n1^n \mid n > 0\} \cup \{0^n1^{2n} \mid n > 0\}$
2. $B_3 = \{a^nb^mc^k \mid k = n+m\}$

Can someone help me? I'm not sure how to deal with the exponents.

Comment: Can you construct a grammar for $\{0^n1^n : n > 0\}$ and for $\{0^n1^{2n} : n>0\}$? If so, you can construct a grammar for $B_2$. If not, I suggest reviewing the material, since these are very basic and standard examples.

Comment: For $B_3$, rewrite it as $\{ a^n b^m c^m c^n : n,m \geq 0 \}$. Now the answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also in a position of still learning (in fact I'm currently taking a Theory of Computation course at school), and I used to have the same problem as you.

The tip that I taught myself and always tell myself is to:

**Look for patterns. The trick is to observe the exponents and see what kind of pattern or relationship they have (e.g. where are the terminal symbols located, how many are there in relation to each other, etc.).**

Let's take grammar $B_2$ as an example.

The condition for the exponent $n$ is $n \gt 0$, so we know that the empty string ($\lambda$ or $\epsilon$ whichever you prefer) is *not* accepted, because if $n = 0$ then $0^01^0 = \lambda$ and $0^01^{2\times0} = \lambda$.

Next, what kind of pattern regarding exponents does the grammar have? First of all, you're very fortunate that there's only one exponent here, which makes it much simpler. Regardless of how the value of $n$ changes, the pattern of the grammar will always follow the same pattern.

For $\{0^n1^n | n > 0\}$, the immediate things we recognize are that: 1) 0's come before 1's, and 2) the number of 0's and 1's are the same.

How could we create a production rule for this?

The first thing to keep in mind is that the position of 0's and 1's doesn't change, so it's better if we anchor them down like this:

$$S \rightarrow 01$$

This takes care of the first string in the grammar, $01$. How do we produce this string in an infinite manner? We could keep repeating the variable $S$'s production, right?

Therefore,

$$S \rightarrow 0S1\ |\ 01$$

This is the context-free grammar for the first portion of $B_2$.

As Mr. Filmus has mentioned in the comments, see for yourself if you can make a context-free grammar for $\{0^n1^{2n} | n \gt 0\}$ *(Hint: How are the placements of 0's and 1's? How many 1's are there for every 0?)*. If you can, then remember the theorem that states: "If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are both context-free grammars, then they are closed under union."

Grammar $B_3$ is a bit trickier, but I think if you keep the tips I gave you in mind it's easily solvable with the same concepts.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas on how to tackle the B2 language.

The exponents are telling us the correlation between the number of 0s and the number of 1s. {0^n 1^n | n > 0} Accepts all strings that starts with an arbitrary amount of 0s, and ends with the same amount of 1s. {0^n 1^2n | n > 0} accepts all strings that starts an arbitrary amount of 0s and ends with the double amount of 1s. The union of these languages will therefore accepts any string satisfying the first language or any string satisfying the other language.

So if we had a CFG S, such that

```
S -> A
A -> 01 | 0A1
```

Would this one be able to create all the strings accepted by the first language?

Can you figure out how to finish the construction of the CFG, so that it also is possible to create strings accepted by the other language?